# How to hide custom template in checkout page for specific products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, customizable-options

I created a custom module which adds an input in shipping method for all products in the checkout page. I want to hide and show this input as per specific category products and replaced this old to new inputs on the checkout page. Does anyone knows this? Thanks in advanced.

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_name/js/view/delivery-date-block</item>
           </item>
        </item>
     </item>
 </item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your extension has a block to render the phtml (I hope it does) you could create a plugin and set a method as follows:

`public function afterToHtml($subject, $result)
{
    if (condition to show is true) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}`

You can see how to create a plugin in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

**[Edit]**

To handle this in the javascript you are going to need to do a few steps:

- Create a configuration for setting which categories you want to hide/show.
- Create a config provider an set your business logic there
- Load the data from your custom config provider at Module_name/js/view/delivery-date-block and set if the template should be visible or not.
- At your template you could use a if binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: @ Thiago Thanks for reply.. Actually I am showing custom input defining in checkout_index_index layout file and setting html template using knockout js file. Can you give me more details on which class I extends with "after" in plugin or how can I hide custom block. sorry for trouble, i am beginner in magento.

Comment: Could you update the description and paste the checkout_index_index.xml, please?

Comment: I updated the description kindly check it and let me know.

Comment: @Rahul here you go

Comment: Thanks @Thiago, Its work for me.  refer this  [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184230/hide-elements-if-input-is-empty)  to hide and show template as per config.

Comment: My pleasure, cheers!